# Horizontal scroll bar in Facebook news feed (homepage)

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, news-feed

See this screen shot before reading further...

[image: screenshot]

I am having this annoying horizontal scroll bar in my Facebook news feed (home page) from last 3-4 days. This is happening only in the news feed (home page) and only in Chrome browser (latest version in Windows 10). Moreover, I have found it only in this URL `www.facebook.com` but not in `m.facebook.com`. It also disappears in any other page (like profile or settings page) or in any other browser. I have double checked my browser's setting, updated it, magnification set to be 100%, PC's resolution is also perfect and also tried clearing cookies. Nothing helped. It looks like some Facebook script is damaged or something gone wrong in Chrome. It's just too annoying! I am just getting curious to know if it is in my browser or something has gone wrong at Facebook's side *or* if there is any solution? (This scroll bar is always there even when not in inspect element mode.)

Comment: Are you using anything that suppresses content, like an ad blocker?

Comment: @AlE. yes I am using UBlock Origin. But, I have added www.facebook.com in the white list.

Comment: Well, it's obviously blocking more than you expect, because there should be a bunch of information in that blank space. I'd say all bets are off if you're messing with the content of a site locally.

Comment: I have removed every third party extension, reset the settings, cleared all cookies and history from the browser. But, it is still there (only in the news feed page). On inspecting the scroll bar, this piece of code seems strange to me `class="tinyViewport tinyWidth"`. I hope if there is any extensive answer _or_ solution to my problem.

Comment: Do you still get the horizontal scroll bar while using an incognito window? Ctrl-Shift-N will open a new one. Incognito windows, by default, don't load any Chrome extensions or apps and when you close all of them the cache/cookies are wiped out giving you a clean testing environment each time.

Comment: @Folk Yes, it is still there but perhaps there is some other reason for it which I am going to write in answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, my curious nature ultimately lead me to the cause of this scroll bar. Here this

[image]

docked menu / drop down or whatever this is dedicated for the pages I administrate. When this was opened, I get a scroll bar and hence quite an empty area as shown in the question. But on closing this menu and then refreshing the page caused the scroll bar to disappear and the empty area as well.

Comment: nice catch! worked for me too...